# How to fetch data after clicking button and limit number of fetch-es

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I would like to use SWAPI (https://swapi.co/) to fetch data, I have created below code, but I am concern that I use too much fetch- that the architecture is wrong.

The plan is: 1st fetch base data (create buttons from them) then click the button and fetch data from another URL and display them (when links are shown, also change them to buttons)

I have created buttons and fetch data (for now `console.log` them)

```
//get the base list of attributes
let mainContent = document.getElementById('mainContent'); // div with id=mainContent
let mainList = new Map();
let mainUrl = fetch('https://swapi.co/api/'); //base URL

mainUrl
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(list => {
    for (let main in list) {
      mainList.set(main, list[main]);
    }
    mainList.forEach((value, key) => {
      createButton(value, key);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => console.error('Caught error: ', err));

let createButton = (value, key) => {
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.setAttribute('name', key);
  button.setAttribute('value', value);
  button.innerHTML = key;
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    return fetch(e.target.value)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(resp => {
         console.log(resp.results);
      });
  });
  mainContent.appendChild(button);
};
```

I expect to list people etc. from clicked URLs but i would expect to use less fetch

Comment: If possible, please if anyone can also provide some useful articles abut this cases, i would be greatfull. Maybe i should not use fetch but HTTPRequest instead?

Comment: JS Bin https://jsbin.com/nepulul/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: It‘s unclear what problem you‘re trying to solve; *“I have created below code, but I am concern that I use too much fetch- that the architecture is wrong.”* is too broad as a problem statement.